# Split a dataframe in two different dataframes

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm working in a data cleaning with R, I'm on my first steps, and I want to divide a dataframe "df" in two different dataframes (df1,df2) of the same size, by rows. I don't know the number of rows of the dataframe, here's what I need:

```
df:
NAME    BIRTH             AGE
Joseph    6/2/1988         28
Jessica   16/3/1975        41
#CONVERT TO 2 DATA FRAMES
df1:
NAME    BIRTH             AGE
Joseph    6/2/1988         28

df2:
NAME    BIRTH             AGE
Jessica   16/3/1975        41
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose if the number of rows is odd, then how are you dividing into same size.

Comment: I need to do it like that because of ram issue, my dataset merging is uisng all my 32 GB of RAM, I want to do it like this and then remerge them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
    index = floor(nrow(df)/2)
    df1 = df[1:index,]
    df2 = df[(index +1) : nrow(df),]
```

It will split your original df into two equal dataframe df1 and df2 in case of nrow(df) = even and df1 will have 1 row less than df2 in case of nrow(df) = odd

Comment: I'm testing it, and post the results. Thanks!